# Битовые маски

Tags: python, c, c++

Поясните как правильно работать с битовыми масками, к примеру у меня есть число

```
a = 0x010f73696e742d3265745f69676f725f32
```

Как посмотреть значение 6 байт, в итоге должен получить

```
73696e742d3265745f69676f725f32
```

Если мне нужно с правой стороны взять только два байта или где-нибудь в середине 4 байта и посмотреть его содержимое. Сложно состоит чтобы извлечь нужные байты из большого числа.

Answer (score 1):

Помните, что все эти операции при желании можно заменить обычными арифметическими. Возьмем Ваш пример с шестью байтами. Шесть байт - это 48 бит. 2^48 = 281474976710656. Значит, нам нужен остаток от деления исходного числа на 281474976710656. Аналогично и с четырьмя байтами из середины. Сдвиг вправо можно эмулировать делением. То есть:

```
right48bits = x % 281474976710656;
middle32bits = right48bits / 65536; // сдвигаем вправо на 16 бит, разделив на 2^16
```

Answer (score 0):

В Python битовые операции хоть и представлены, но использовать такие низкоуровневые операции в языке с динамической типизацией довольно таки странно.

Если же вас интересуют побитовые операции в С или С++, то там (как и в python) все это можно осуществить с помощью обычных операторов битового сдвига (>>, <<, и т.п.) и битовой логики. Ничего сложного в этом нет, задачи абсолютно тривиальные.

Comment: Уже все решилось, разобрался все просто. Был вопрос с длинными числами когда нельзя применить маску. Вопрос у меня был и сейчас решен, но думал можно было по другом. Смотрю разные варианты, интересно экспериментировать.